# automatically execute OnCheckedChangedListener when a check box is setChecked(true) in code

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

Suppose I have a bunch of checkboxes in a listview.

I'm fetching some data from DB to set checked to those checkboxes.

Each checkbox have some specific chekedListeners.

If a checkbox is checked if found to be needed checked from DB, will the `OnCheckedChangedListener` work?

I'm facing a problem,

```
if (type.equals("technicalskills") || type.equals("programmingskills")) {
    listChecked = Base.user_technical_skills.split(",");
    setChecked(mHolder.mCheck,listChecked,i);
    if (i == 1 && type.equals("technicalskills") && ((Base.user_technical_skills.contains("MS-Office") && listChecked.length > 1) || (!Base.user_technical_skills.contains("MS-Office") && listChecked.length > 0))) {
        position == 1;
        mHolder.mCheck.setChecked(true);
        //UserDetails.prog_listView_container.setExpanded(true);
    }
}

mHolder.mCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean b) {
        if(type.equals("technicalskills") && position == 1) {
            if (b) {
                UserDetails.prog_listView_container.expand();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                    UserDetails.prog_listView.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    UserDetails.prog_listView.animate()
                            .alpha(1.0f)
                            .setDuration(800);
                }
            } else {
                UserDetails.prog_listView_container.collapse();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                    UserDetails.prog_listView.animate()
                            .alpha(0.0f)
                            .setDuration(800);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

this entire code is inside a getView() method of an Adapter extending BaseAdapter

when I'm setting `mcheck.setChecked(true);` by code, the `OnCheckedChangedListener` is not executed.

Comment: OnCheckedChangedListener will always call after any change in checkbox , no bother about it change made by pragmatically or by user

Comment: put your code here for more understanding.

Comment: Added code… please help…

Comment: @srv242 have you debugged and checked whether it's calling or it's failing in some of your condition inside it

Comment: Its reaching `UserDetails.prog_listView_container.expand();` but it is not working when setting checked programmatically but working manually.

Comment: @srv242 check the flow when you do manually and programmatically.... You can find where it lags...

Comment: if the `setChecked(true)` is being invoked before `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`, then yes it will do nothing. otherwise, when `setChecked()` is invoked even from your code, the listener will be notified `onCheckedChanged()` check this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/CompoundButton.java#CompoundButton.setChecked%28boolean%29 **see lines starting from 153**